# How to stop Stateful Widget from Re-initialising

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have **2** Scaffolds. The first is **Menu**, the second is **Places**.

```
Menu -> Places
```

The Menu/1st scaffold fetches api/future data on `initState()`. What I'm trying to achieve is being able to go the **2nd/ Places page** and then when I **return** to the Menu page, is **must not reload** the Future/ initState again.

The first page(Menu) scaffold has something like this, which works perfectly:

```
//First Scaffold

Future myFuture;
  bool _loading;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = _getService();
    _loading = true;
  }
```

The second page/scaffold has something like this to return to the previous page (which when pressed re-loads the initState of the previous page):

```
//Second Scaffold


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
```

**So how can I stop it from initialising the state when going back to that screen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are adding new instance of the `Menu` page.

### You end up with the following stack

`Menu page | Place page | Menu page`

So at this point you have 2 **Menu** pages, one before **Places** page and one after it.
The right way to do it is to pop the `Places` page so that you will return to the `Menu` page.

### You need to do this

```
icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
```

#### From the Menu page you should use the following code to navigate to Places

```
     Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Places()));
```

Comment: It then pops to a blank screen

Comment: Post that code that you use to go to Places page

Comment: I've just posted it.

Comment: Check my edit. I guess you are replacing the Menu with Places, that's why you have blank screen. Don't use `pushPlacement` in the Menu, use `push`.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you very much, I needed to update both pages like you said, makes sense to me know and works, thank you.